# Need script to click button on website that downloads a file

Tags: download, applescript

I am new to this so this is probably a dumb question but....

I am trying to get a download to happen off a website by clicking on a link but I don't think I have my code right for AppleScript.

The script opens the right website, but when I try to get it to download the file I need by clicking "export data" the code below doesnt seem to do anything, and am not sure what I am missing/did wrong. No error code. Just doesnt do anything.

Website [Here](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=50&type=c%2C6%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C21%2C23%2C39%2C35%2C34%2C41%2C42%2C43%2C104%2C107%2C110%2C206%2C209%2C211%2C50%2C61&season=2019&month=0&season1=2019&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0)

```
to clickId(LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV & "').click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickId
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What language is this? Or is this just pseudo-code?

Comment: Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow! Your example is not very clear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 

Also, you don't need to worry about asking dumb questions! We are all here to learn. If you haven't already, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier for contributors to help you with the problem :)

Comment: @mancristiana thanks for the advice - I tried to fix the post to make more sense.

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will open a new **Safari** *window* to the designated **URL**, wait for the *page* to finish loading, then click the **Export Data** *link* to download the **FanGraphs Leaderboard.csv** file.

- **Note:** This was tested on **macOS High Sierra**, however for **macOS Mojave** and later there is a note in the `waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()` *handler* to modify its *code*. Don't forget to do it if applicable.
- To use **JavaScript** with **AppleScript** and **Safari** the **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu, which is hidden by default, must be checked. It can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced**

```
set theURL to "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=50&type=c%2c6%2c11%2c12%2c13%2c21%2c23%2c39%2c35%2c34%2c41%2c42%2c43%2c104%2c107%2c110%2c206%2c209%2c211%2c50%2c61&season=2019&month=0&season1=2019&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0"

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

my waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()

my clickId("LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV")


--  # Handlers:

to clickId(ElementID)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & ElementID & "').click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickId

on waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()
    --  # NOTE: For macOS Mojave and later, change 'UI element 1' to 'UI element 2` in the code below.  
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (accessibility description of ¬
            button 1 of UI element 1 of every group of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page") contains "Reload this page"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
end waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>