# Applescript Waiting for Safari Page Element to load before continue

Tags: safari, applescript, element, loading, wait

I try to have my Applescript to wait until a specific element on a web page is loaded, before clicking on it; but it is not working. The clicking does in fact work, but it doesn't wait until the ElementByName is loaded.

The complete code:

```
to clickName(theName, elementnum)

    tell application "Safari"
        tell front document to repeat until (do JavaScript ¬
            "document.contains(document.getElementByName('" & theName & "'))")
            delay 1
        end repeat -- Finished loading

        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1

    end tell

end clickName
clickName("xxx", 0)
```

This part is not doing what I want:

```
        tell front document to repeat until (do JavaScript ¬
            "document.contains(document.getElementByName('" & theName & "'))")
            delay 1
        end repeat -- Finished loading
```

It just continues with the rest of the code, without checking if element 'xxx' is already loaded and therefor might miss the click event.

Please advice.

Comment: In order for me to test your code I'd have to provide my own URL and name of element, sorry but that's not how it's done here. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Personally, I always jut wait until a page finishes loading as then I'm sure my remaining code has its best shot of succeeding, and for that I use my `waitForPageToFinishLoadingInSafari()` handler. You can see it in my answer to: [Need script to click button on website that downloads a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164211/need-script-to-click-button-on-website-that-downloads-a-file/61164748#61164748)

Comment: @user3439894 unfortunately I the URL cannot be shared, because it is inside a bank portal. The clicking of the link does in fact work, but I think the way how I formulated the 'repeat' function, is not correct.

Comment: Since you haven't provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd suggest you read the [repeat Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362) section in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). As currently written, it's expecting a _boolean_. and it's not getting one.